# JSX styles are not working for Storybook after an upgrade

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, next.js, styled-jsx

I upgraded my project from NextJS 10 to NextJS 12. Everything is working except for Storybook, which has no styles now.

I am using `styled-jsx` library to generate embedded `css`, using it as:

```
const SearchResult = ({ onClick, vehicle }: SearchResultProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div className="search-result" data-testid="search-result" onClick={onClick}>
      <style jsx>{styles}</style>
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

It generates styles like `class="jsx-2615582530 search-result"`. Before the update, it would also embed a style `search-result.jsx-2615582530` into the generated storybook. Now, the jsx style names are there, yet the styles are gone.

I upgraded `styled-jsx` from `3.3.1` to `5.0.0` and NextJS to 12.0.3. Did not change any loaders or anything. My guess, webpack might have easily gotten upgraded.

My config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = ({ config }) => {
  // Fill in process.env on the client
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.serializedEnv': {},
    })
  );

  // Sentry requires different packages for front and back end,
  // but in storybook we know it's always client side
  config.resolve.alias = {
    'sentry-alias': '@sentry/browser',
    '@/remoteConfig': './standardRemoteConfig',
  };

  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.md$/,
    loader: "raw-loader",
  }),

  config.externals = [...(config.externals || []), 'fs', 'net'];

  config.resolve.extensions.push('.md');

  config.resolve.fallback = {
    "https": false,
    "stream": false,
  };

  return config;
};
```

and main

```
module.exports = {
  core: {
    builder: 'webpack5',
  },
  stories: ['../stories/**/*.stories.tsx'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-actions',
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-backgrounds',
    '@storybook/addon-knobs',
    '@storybook/addon-viewport',
    '@storybook/addon-a11y',
    'storybook-addon-paddings',
  ],
};
```

Further, if I include styles as `<style>{styles}</style>` without the `jsx` prop, they are included in the produced storybook.

Only, the text is displayed weird:

[image: vertically printed CSS]

When `jsx` is there, `<style />` is missing from the resulting markup, altogether.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer `styled-jsx` required the following:

```
+import { StyleRegistry } from 'styled-jsx';
```

and

```
-export const decorators = [withPaddings, withRedux(), (story: Function) => <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>{story()}</I18nextProvider>]
+export const decorators = [(Story) => (
+  <StyleRegistry>
+    <Story />
+  </StyleRegistry>
+), withPaddings, withRedux(), (story: Function) => <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>{story()}</I18nextProvider>]
```

This yet again makes embedded jsx styles present.

Comment: To clarify for anyone unfamiliar, this is added to Storybook's `preview.js`. You'll need to add the import from the top, and then add <StyleRegistry> around one of your story decorators.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who finds this, the solution for me was to update `styled-jsx` to 5.0.4, as we're on Next 12 and have `styled-jsx` explicitly listed as a dependency.

If you have `styled-jsx` in your package.json, make sure it's at the appropriate version (my guess is >=5.)